# Argument for extenstion of the Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Could anyone please point out if there is any mistakes in the following arguments for the extension of the Fourier transform from $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$:

"Since the compactly supported $C^{\infty}$-functions are dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, as shown in [13], and these functions are contained in the Schwartz-class by definition, the same holds for $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.
As a consequence of this fact, all the result that will henceforth be stated for Schwartz-functions carries over (in some adequate sense, e.g. almost everywhere) to the whole space $L^2$ by an approximation procedure that will not be carried out explicitly.
We can now state the Fourier inversion theorem, which proof can be found in the appendix.

Proposition. For every $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ the following integral formula holds

$$f(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty} ^\infty \widehat{f}(\omega) \mathrm{e}^{2\pi i \omega x} \mathrm{d}\omega.$$

Consequently, the Fourier transform acts bijectively on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, the inversion theorem implies, and can be shown to be equivalent to, Plancherel's theorem which states that the Fourier transform preserves the norm of every $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. the energy of a signal equals the energy of its transform.

Proposition.

For $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ there holds

$$\int\limits_{-\infty} ^\infty \ |f(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{-\infty} ^\infty \ |\hat{f}(\omega)|^2 \mathrm{d}\omega$$

In particular this means that the Fourier transform is also a unitary operator, and hence an isometry on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Consequently, we can extend the Fourier transform to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as follows. Since $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, for every $f\in L^2$ there exists a sequence $f_n\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $\lVert f_n-f\rVert\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, by Plancherel we have $$\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert=\lVert \widehat{f}_n-\widehat{f}_m\rVert$$ so $\widehat{f}_n$ is a Cauchy-sequence in $L^2$, and hence converges to a unique limit which we define as the Fourier transform of $f$. So $\mathcal{F}$ extends to a unitary operator on the whole space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and consequently the Fourier transform acts isometrically on this space."

Thank's a lot for your attention

Comment: There's a detail that is missing: Showing that $\lim_n \hat{f_n}$ has the same $L^{2}$ limit, regardless of the chosen sequence $\{ f_n \}$ that converges in $L^{2}$ to $f \in L^{2}$. You can easily verify this detail, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: Thank's for the comment, although I mention just before in the text that $\mathcal{F}$ maps $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ into itself, and the uniqueness follows from $L^2$ being a Banach-space.

Comment: The uniqueness is not just a consequence of $L^{2}$ being a Banach space.

Comment: What I meant is that $\mathcal{F}$ maps $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ into a dense subset of $L^2$ namely itself, and uniqueness of the sequence follows from the inversion formula, and $L^2$ being a Banach space.

Comment: The sequence $\{ f_n \}$ is not unique. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say independence, not uniqueness. I think the following argument works, but please correct me if I'm wrong or if you have a cleaner argument: If $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ Cauchy seq. in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=lim_{n\to\infty}g_n=f$, then $lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)-g_n(x)=lim_{n\to\infty}\int (\hat{f_n}(\omega)-\hat{g_n}(\omega))e^{2\pi  i x\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega=0$ implies that $lim_n \lVert{\hat{f}_n-\hat{g}_n}\rVert=0$.

Comment: If $\{f_n \}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are in $\mathcal{S}$ and converge in $L^{2}$ to some $f \in L^{2}$, then $\{\hat{f}_n\}$ and $\{\hat{g}_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $L^{2}$ by Plancherel's Theorem and, hence, both converge in $L^{2}$ (not necessarily pointwise) to limits $F$ and $G$ respectively. And $F=G$ because $\|F-G\|\le\lim_n\{\|F-\hat{f}_n\|+\|f_n-g_n\|+\|\hat{g}_n-G\|\}=0$. You have to work Plancherel into this, not pointwise. What you have is the unique continuous extension of a bounded operator.

Comment: Ok, yes that one is better. Thanks!